# Jasmine Testing Controller and mock returned data in Service Promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

i have a problem when mocking a data service promise.

I use AngularJS and Jasmine 2.2.0

My Code is:

**Controller**

```
app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'ngAppSettings', 'homeViewModel', 'storageService', 'homeService',
function ($scope, ngAppSettings, homeViewModel, storageService, homeService) {

    $scope.applicationName = ngAppSettings.applicationName;

    $scope.model = homeViewModel;

    storageService.getStorageAuth().then(function (data) {

        $scope.model.userName= data.name;

    }, function (err) {
        alert(err.errors[0].message);
    });

}]);
```

**Service**

```
app.service('storageService', ['$q', 'ngAppSettings', 'localStorageService',
function ($q, ngAppSettings, localStorageService) {

    this.getStorageAuth = function () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

            var userAuth = localStorageService.get(ngAppSettings.storageUser);
            if (userAuth) {
                data = userAuth;
            }

        deferred.resolve(data);

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}]);
```

**Test Spec**

```
describe('Controllers: homeController', function () {
var $rootScope;
var $scope;
var ctrl;
var $q;
var deferred;
var storageService;

beforeEach(module('IspFrontEndTemplateApp'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_, _storageService_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    storageService = _storageService_;

    deferred = $q.defer();

    spyOn(storageService, "getStorageAuth").and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
}));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('homeController', { $scope: $scope });
}));

it('UserName is: UsuarioTeste', function () {

    deferred.resolve({
        isAuth: true,
        userName: "UsuarioTeste",
        name: "UsuarioTeste"
    });

    expect($scope.model.userName).toBe('UsuarioTeste');
});
});
```

The error is: Expected '' to be 'UsuarioTeste'.

I need test my model properties in controller but the value is not refreshed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `$digest` one more time in your test:

```
$scope.$digest();
expect($scope.model.userName).toBe('UsuarioTeste'); // will work
```

The reason is that promises are resolved asynchronously in the sense that a promise never calls its success or error callbacks within the same `$apply` it has been created in, even if it has been resolved. Code could be hard to read if you create a promise in the beginning of your function and the effect of the resolved promise would be already observable a few lines later.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly that